# PIL ValueError: Images do not match when using alpha_composite to draw a transparent image onto another image

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am making a Python script that fetches the Fortnite Item Shop from an API, saves all information needed and then draws the image of the item in the shop onto an image, however I get a ValueError: images do not match. All images are the same resolution and are all in PNG format, but the PIL documentation doesn't explain much to me.

```
# Importing JSON handling library for parsing GET request using requests library
import json
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

# Creating blank lists & variables for later use
featured_list = []
daily_list = []
inc = 0

# API Endpoint
url = "https://fnbr.co/api/shop"

# API key
key = "ee9f93b4-2a91-4681-96b7-3f9485c9b14c" # key is usually here

# Defining Parameters
headers = {"x-api-key":key}

# Sending GET request
req = requests.get(url = url, headers = headers)

# Converting request data into JSON format
info = req.json()

# Finds appropriate pieces of data for Featured Item Shop
info = info['data']['featured']
for x in info:
    featured_name = x['name']
    featured_rarity = x['rarity']
    featured_icon_url = x['images']['icon']
    print(featured_name, featured_rarity, featured_icon_url)
    if featured_rarity == "marvel":
        imgpath = "/home/pi/Desktop/Item Shop/Rarity/Marvel.png"
        bg = Image.open(imgpath)
        response = requests.get(featured_icon_url)
        f_icon = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))

        final1 = Image.new("RGBA", bg.size)
        final1 = Image.alpha_composite(final1, bg)
        final1 = Image.alpha_composite(final1, f_icon)
        final1.save("final{}.png".format(inc))
        inc += 1

    else:
        break




# Converts request data into JSON format again to access Daily Item Shop
info = req.json()

# Finds appropriate pieces of data for Daily Item Shop
info = info['data']['daily']
for y in info:
    daily_name = y['name']
    daily_rarity = y['rarity']
    daily_icon_url = y['images']['icon']
    print(daily_name, daily_rarity, daily_icon_url)
```

Error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Item Shop/bot.py", line 45, in <module>
    final1 = Image.alpha_composite(final1, f_icon)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2837, in alpha_composite
    return im1._new(core.alpha_composite(im1.im, im2.im))
ValueError: images do not match
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you upload your `Marvel.png`?

Comment: Two possible reasons:1. they have the different size.2.they have the different mode.

Comment: They are both 512x512, I've verified that. How do I tell if they're different modes and how do I overcome that?